# Is there a equivalent to the automatic mod downloader ModCraft for mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Mac and I use Mods, I am not very good at putting mods on and have looked at endless youtube video's. I found one where you make the minecraft.jar into a folder then drag the files in but that only works for toomanyitem's mod. So tried something called ModCraft but soon found out it is only for windows. So I was wondering if there was a equivalent.

Comment: Keep in mind that official modding support will be added into the game, where you'll be able to install mods from inside of Minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

I happen to have written a few scripts that aid in the mod installing process. You can find them [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2298862/modscripts.zip).

Unzip the file and you'll find two .command files, open.command and close.command. To install some mods, double-click open.command. It'll run in Terminal and will create a folder called 'minecraft' on the desktop. Drag in the class files for the mod. Then double-click close.command. That's it! Now just open Minecraft and have fun using your mods.